# Detect corner coordinates of a non-convex polygon in clockwise order MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, polygon, corner-detection, non-convex

I have some images which includes both convex as well as non-convex polygons. Each image contains exactly one polygon. I need to detect the corner coordinates and need to sort them in clock-wise or counter-clockwise order. For convex polygons, I use [Harris corner detection](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/corner-detection.html) for detecting corners and [convexhull](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) for sorting the points. But i dont have any idea on how to sort non-convex polygon. As my inputs are images, i think some **Image Processing** Technique might help to sort them out by moving alongside the edge of the polygon. Is there any way with least complexity?

**Example Image:**

I have named the corners randomly.

[image]

**Expected output:**

I expect Corner coordinates in this order
`1 3 5 9 4 2 8 7 6 10` or `1 10 6 7 8 2 4 9 5 3`. You can start at any point, not necessarily `1`

**Edit 1:**

After [rayryeng's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) solution, which works for all convex polygons as well as for some non-convex polygon, there are some non-convex polygons which doesn't go well with his algorithm.

**Here is an example**

[image]

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123125/detect-correct-number-of-corner-coordinates-from-a-polygon-image-in-matlab?rq=1).

Comment: The problem is not detecting the corners, its obtaining them in clockwise/counter-clockwise order.

Comment: If you were to obtain the order manually, what would that order be? What yo you expec? You haven't defined your expected output.  I think your question could be improved by making it more defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach is to use [`bwdistgeodesic`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdistgeodesic.html) to find order the corners by their distance along your edge. This should work for any polygon where you can detect a continuous edge.

We start by loading in the image from Stack Overflow and converting it into a black and white image to make it easier to find the edge

```
A = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpbpP.jpg');
A_bw = im2bw(A,100/255);  %binary image
A_bw1 = imcomplement(A_bw);   %inverted binary image
```

The `bwmorph` function provides a lot of options for manipulating black and white images. We're going to use the `remove` option to find the edge of our polygon, but you could also use another edge detector if you prefer.

```
%Find the edges
A_edges = bwmorph(A_bw, 'remove');
[edge_x, edge_y] = find(A_edges');
```

Let's visualize the edges we detected

```
figure; imshow(A_edges);
```

[image: A_edges]

Okay, we have a nice clear continuous edge. Now let's find the corners. I use `corner`, but you could substitute your favorite corner detector

```
A_corners = corner(A_bw1, 'QualityLevel',.3);
```

Let's visualize our initial corner ordering

```
figure; imshow(A_bw1);
hold on
plot(A_corners(:,1), A_corners(:,2), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18)
text(A_corners(:,1), A_corners(:,2), strsplit(num2str(1:length(A_corners))), 'Color', 'g', 'FontSize', 24);
hold off
```

[image: Corners in Initial order]

Another thing you might not notice, is that they are not directly on the edges. I'll start by finding the closest point along the edge to each corner point, and then I'll visualize corners in red and the closest edge points in green.

```
[~, ind] = min(pdist2(A_corners, [edge_x, edge_y]), [], 2);
A_edge_corners = [edge_x(ind), edge_y(ind)];

figure; imshow(A_edges);
hold on;
plot(A_corners(:,1), A_corners(:,2), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18)
plot(A_edge_corners(:,1), A_edge_corners(:,2),'g.', 'MarkerSize', 18)
hold off;
```

[image: Corner offset from edge]

To calculate the distance around the edge for each corner, we'll use the corner point approximation, `A_edge_corners` (green point) on the edge rather than the corner point itself `A_corners` (red point).

Now we have all the pieces we need to use `bwdistgeodesic`. This function finds the distance to a seed point for each non-zero pixel in a black and white image. We are interested in the distance from an initial corner to each point on the edge. Let's try it out.

```
% Calculate distance from seed corner
first_corner = A_edge_corners(1,:);
D = bwdistgeodesic(A_edges, first_corner(1), first_corner(2));
figure; imagesc(D);
```

[image: D]

We're starting from the right most corner and the pixels moving away from the corner increase in value. But this isn't quite what we want. If we order the corners using these values, we end up with an ordering in distance from the initial point.

```
[~, corner_order] = sort(D(sub2ind(size(D), A_edge_corners(:,2), A_edge_corners(:,1))));
A_corners_reorder1 = A_corners(corner_order, :);

figure; imshow(A_bw1);
hold on
plot(A_corners_reorder1(:,1), A_corners_reorder1(:,2),'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18)
text(A_corners_reorder1(:,1), A_corners_reorder1(:,2), strsplit(num2str(1:length(A_corners))), 'Color', 'g', 'FontSize', 24);
hold off
```

[image: Corners Reorder from 1st point]

To solve this problem, we just have to break the edge so that the ordering only goes in one direction from the initial point. If you are interested in a clockwise or a counter-clockwise ordering, you would need to break the edge according to a set of rules depending on the orientation of the edge. If the direction doesn't matter you can simply find an adjacent pixel to the initial corner, and break the edge there.

```
%Break the edge into one path by removing a pixel adjacent to first corner
%If the corner is near the edge of the image, you would need to check for
%edge conditions
window = A_edges(first_corner(2)-1:first_corner(2)+1, first_corner(1)-1:first_corner(1)+1);
window(2,2) = 0; %Exclude the corner itself
[x, y] = find(window, 1);
A_edges(first_corner(2)+x-2, first_corner(1)+y-2) = 0;  

figure; imshow(A_edges);
hold on;
plot(first_corner(1), first_corner(2), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18)
hold off;
```

[image: Show broken edges]

Now the distance from the initial point along the edge can only follow one path

```
%Find order the pixels along edge
D = bwdistgeodesic(A_edges, first_corner(1), first_corner(2));
figure; imagesc(D);
```

[image: D]

This gives us the desired ordering of edges

```
[~, corner_order] = sort(D(sub2ind(size(D), A_edge_corners(:,2), A_edge_corners(:,1))));
A_corners = A_corners(corner_order, :);

figure; imshow(A_bw1);
hold on
plot(A_corners(:,1), A_corners(:,2),'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18)
text(A_corners(:,1), A_corners(:,2), strsplit(num2str(1:length(A_corners))), 'Color', 'g', 'FontSize', 24);
hold off
```

[image: Correct ordering]

This method also works on polygons that are unbalanced with respect to the centroid, such as the second demo image.

[image: second demo image]

For fun, I present a third image, which has a vertex on the opposite side of the centroid, as a clearer example of an unbalanced polygon. My method also correctly parses this image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very nice. Didn't know that function existed.

Comment: Amazing except i don't understand the process. Would you please edit your code to make it more understandable, and also there needs a correction in the 2nd new image. The point 6 is supposed to be in vertex but it seems to be showing an edge. Also 2 points are missing in image 1. Once done, i'll mark this as solution

Comment: @SanthanSalai I've added a bunch of explanation, but accidentally added the problems that you fixed back in. The missing points and points on the edge are due to errors with the corner detector. Fixing the threshold and other parameters should fix this. I'll get to these fixes soon.

Comment: That's not a problem. Great explanation. Too bad that i can't up-vote this answer twice. Would you mind if i fix those missing points?

Comment: @SanthanSalai It would be a lot of images to fix, but if you're up for it, go ahead.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem in image processing.  The typical answer is to find the centroid of the shape, and find the angle between the centroid and each corner point.  You would make sure that the angles are represented so that they range between `[0,360)` degrees.  Once you have this, you **sort** the angles then use the resulting order to determine the order of the points.

The image that you presented requires a bit of pre-preprocessing so I can start working on it.  I read in the image directly from StackOverflow, then I invert the image so that the black star becomes white.  I also need to remove the numbers, so I employ [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) to remove any small areas of text.  Once that's done, I perform a corner detection on this image via [`corner`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corner.html), and I set the `QualityFactor` to 0.3 so I can detect the 10 corners.  Very specifically:

```
%// Read image from StackOverflow
im = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpbpP.jpg'));

%// Threshold the image and area open it
im_thresh = im <= 100;
im_open = bwareaopen(im_thresh, 50);

%// Detect corner points
out = corner(im_open, 'QualityLevel', 0.3);

%// Show the image with the corner points
imshow(im_open);
hold on
plot(out(:,1), out(:,2), 'r.')
```

`im_open` contains our final processed image.  This is what I get:

[image]

---

Now, let's find the centroid.  This can simply be done by finding the coordinates of the non-zero locations, and finding the average of each dimension:

```
[rows, cols] = find(im_open);
cenX = mean(cols);
cenY = mean(rows);
```

`cenX` and `cenY` contain the `(x,y)` locations of the centroid of the image.  Just to be sure we have it right:

```
imshow(im_open);
hold on;
plot(cenX, cenY, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18);
```

We get:

[image]

Very nice.  Now, `out` in the earlier code contains `(x,y)` points of the corner points.  All you have to do is determine the angle from the centroid to each corner point, then sort the angles.  You would use this sorting order to rearrange the corner points to give you your arranged points.  If you want **clockwise**, you would need to sort the values in **ascending** order.  If you want **counter-clockwise**, you would need to sort in **descending** order.  I'll leave that up to you on what you want to decide, but I'll write code that will allow you to do both.  Therefore, simply do this:

```
%// Determine angles (in degrees)
angles = atan2d(out(:,2) - cenY, out(:,1) - cenX);

%// Any negative angles, add 360 degrees to convert to positive
angles(angles < 0) = 360 + angles(angles < 0);

%// Sort the angles
[~,ind] = sort(angles); %// clockwise
%[~,ind] = sort(angles, 'descend'); %// counter-clockwise

%// Re-arrange the corner points to respect the order
out_reorder = out(ind,:);
```

Now the final test is to plot these points and also plot a number beside each point to see if we got it right.  That can be done by:

```
%// Show image
imshow(im_open);
hold on;
%// Show points
plot(out_reorder(:,1), out_reorder(:,2), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 18);

%// Place a textbox at each point and show a sequence number
for idx = 1 : size(out_reorder,1)
    text(out_reorder(idx,1), out_reorder(idx,2), num2str(idx), 'FontSize', 24, 'Color', 'green');
end
```

We get:

[image]

Looks good to me!  As such, `out_reorder` gives you the corner points so that they follow either a clockwise order, or counter-clockwise order.  Each row that you encounter in succession gives you the next point that naturally follows the clockwise or counter-clockwise order you seek.

Also take note of where the numbering starts.  The angle of 0 is defined by a horizontal line that points to the east with respect to the centroid.  Therefore, the closest point to 0 as we are starting in ascending order is where you see the number 1.  After the 1, you see that it sweeps in clockwise order until we run out of corner points.

Comment: Will this work for any non-convex shape? I doubt that because, in your last image(after numbering), if the point `2` is very low so that the centroid shifts to the bottom slightly, wont the `5` and `6` get reversed? I'm not complaining, just having a doubt whether it will work for any non-convex shape. Anyway thanks for the detailed explanation. +1

Comment: @SanthanSalai - That's true I suppose.  You could modify it so that you take the **distance** of the corner point to the centroid into account.  If that's the case, I'll leave that as a learning exercise.  You could also make the centroid location robust to that kind of noise by taking a look at a histogram of points, and the smaller the bin count per coordinate, the less it should be weighted.  There are things you can do to circumvent that, but the general procedure to sort points in a clockwise/counter-clockwise order is to do what I did above.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - If you could also upload an image where you believe the algorithm above may fail, I'd like to see one and test it.  In any case, this is something to get you started.  Only way to see if it may or may not work is if you test it on images yourself.

Comment: I understand your point, the general case works always(100%) for convex polygons, may or might not  work correctly for non-convex polygons. hence the title. Testing with some images and will let you know if i find any such image.

Comment: Great. I'll try working on the algorithm. Stay tuned